# Can GruntJS remove the bower_components folder after copying files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, bower

I am using Bower and GruntJS.  I thought that grunt-bowercopy would remove the `bower_components` folder when it is done but this is not happening.

Can grunt-bowercopy remove the bower_components folder after copying the files to the locations I want?

Here is my folder setup:

```
->Project
    ->Themes
        ->Theme
            ->assets
                ->scripts
                ->styles
    ->tools
        ->build
            ->bower_components
            ->bower.json
            ->gruntfile.js
            ->package.json
```

Here is how I am running grunt-bowercopy in my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Loads the necessary tasks for this Grunt file.
    require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        bowercopy: {
          options: {
            clear: true
          },
          js: {
            options: {
                destPrefix: '../../Themes/Theme/assets/'
            },
            //The key is the destination file.  The value is the file from the bower_components folder
            //The files will be added to a scripts folder at the location: ../../themes/3MTheme/assets/scripts
            //The key is the name of the folder that is copied into the /assets folder.
            src : 'scripts'

          },
          css: {
            options: {
                destPrefix: '../../Themes/Theme/assets/'
            },
            src: 'styles'

          }
       }

      // Custom task, executed via the command "grunt bowercopy"
      grunt.registerTask('bower', ['bowercopy']);
};
```

Comment: If it removes bower_components folder after you build the project, you will need to install these components again for the next build, right? Why do you want to remove that folder? It's only for development purpose and doesn't go into dist folder.

Comment: @Sergey, I'm copying some files from a shared server.  These files may be updated by others occassionally and I'd like to make sure I pull down those most recent updates.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the asnswer.  I was using `clear: true` in the options when it should be `clean: true`

This works in my gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Loads the necessary tasks for this Grunt file.
require('matchdep').filterDev('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    bowercopy: {
      options: {
        clean: true
      },
      js: {
        options: {
            destPrefix: '../../Themes/Theme/assets/'
        },
        //The key is the destination file.  The value is the file from the bower_components folder
        //The files will be added to a scripts folder at the location: ../../themes/3MTheme/assets/scripts
        //The key is the name of the folder that is copied into the /assets folder.
        src : 'scripts'

      },
      css: {
        options: {
            destPrefix: '../../Themes/Theme/assets/'
        },
        src: 'styles'

      }
   }

  // Custom task, executed via the command "grunt bowercopy"
  grunt.registerTask('bower', ['bowercopy']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem as if grunt-bowercopy does this for you, but I've done something similar for clearing reports before running test commands.

Just create your own custom task called something like cleanbowercopy which executes an [rmdir](https://www.npmjs.org/package/rmdir) on the directory you are cleaning.

Then update your register task to call it after bowercopy:

```
grunt.registerTask('bower',['bowercopy','cleanbowercopy']);
```

That way it will accomplish what you are seeking within the same command, and can even be reused if you'd rather clean the dir at a different point in time.

Comment: Thank you!  That's a really good idea.  It looks like grunt-bowercopy will remove the bower_components folder, I just didn't spot my mistake until right after I posted it here.